# MySQL DATE_SUB function not working as expected

Tags: mysql

I have following query, to fetch the events .

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  events_table 
WHERE event_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
ORDER BY event_status ASC,
  event_date ASC
```

All I want to do is return all rows whose event_date is `today`

Where I m going wrong?
Thanks for help

Comment: Does it has timestamp or just date column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this in your where clause:

```
WHERE DATE(event_date) = DATE(NOW())
```

And another option that wouldn't prevent using an index on event_date:

```
WHERE event_date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: well date could be future date as well, I want to show how many events for today, this week and this month are there. The result includes past as well as future events. Just want to show total events on today. this week and this month.

Comment: @Sharmila - if that's the case, then just use the date you are querying for instead of `CURDATE` in the query and it should give you the events for that date.  If you want it by month, then use the start and end dates of the month.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`CURDATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate):

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  events_table 
WHERE event_date > CURDATE()
ORDER BY event_status ASC,
  event_date ASC
```

This is assuming that event_date can't be in the future... otherwise you'll want to also use the `DATE()` function:

```
WHERE DATE(event_date) = CURDATE()
```

Comment: well date could be future date as well, I want to show how many events for today, this week and this month are there. The result includes past as well as future events. Just want to show total events on today, this week and this month.